# how to stop to navigation , once performing click event on specific part on a tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see image , I'll have to change background of purple part on click, But it should not navigate to website, when click on purple part, right now it's navigating to website after change the color.

HTML

```
  <div>
          <a  href="https://www.google.com/" style="height: 100px; width:400px; background: lightblue; display: block; padding: 20px;">
              
              <div id="chnageMe" style="background: purple; padding: 10px; color:white">Hello shuibham</div>
              
        
          </a>
        </div>
```

Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#chnageMe').click(function(){
        alert('dfsdfsd');
          $('#chnageMe').css('background', 'yellow');
      })
    </script>][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `Event.prototype.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser from doing the "default" behavior of navigating to the `href`.

It would look like this:

```js
      $('#chnageMe').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert('dfsdfsd');
          $('#chnageMe').css('background', 'yellow');
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action for the click event on the  tag is to follow the link. You can prevent the default action using `preventDefault()`. The click event itself is available as a parameter in the event handler function.

Sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

```js
$('#chnageMe').click(function(evt) { // evt is our click event
  evt.preventDefault() // prevent the link from following the URL
  alert('dfsdfsd');
  $('#chnageMe').css('background', 'yellow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
          <a  href="https://www.google.com/" style="height: 100px; width:400px; background: lightblue; display: block; padding: 20px;">
              
              <div id="chnageMe" style="background: purple; padding: 10px; color:white">Hello shuibham</div>
              
        
          </a>
        </div>
```